# How to return multiple types & values in multiple files in C++

Tags: c++

I am having trouble in returning multiple types. I know there are a few people who had trouble with this but mine is different. I'm using header files and they're not. So here is my code.

```
//in Fruit.h
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std; 

class Fruit { 
private:    
    string Fruitname;   
    int Fruitamount; 
public:     
    Fruit(string name, int amount);     
    tuple(string, int) getFruitStats(); 
    ~Fruit(); 
};
```

in the C++ file

```
//in Fruit.cpp
#include "Fruit.h"
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;
Fruit::Fruit(string name, int amount)
{
     Fruitname = name;
     Fruitamount = amount;
}
tuple<string,int> Fruit::getFruitStats() {

}

Fruit::~Fruit()
{
}
```

The error messages as follows:

1. no instance of overloaded function "Fruit::Fruit" matches the specified type line 7 **in Fruit.cpp**
2. member "Fruit::string" is not a type name line 7 **in Fruit.cpp**
3. C2597 illegal reference to non-static member 'Fruit::string' line 7 **in Fruit.cpp**
4. C2146 syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'name' line 7 **in Fruit.cpp**
5. C2143 syntax error: missing ';' before '{' line 8 **in Fruit.cpp**
6. C2447 '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) line 8 **in Fruit.cpp**
7. class "Fruit" has no member "getFruitStats" line 12 **in Fruit.cpp**
8. C2556 'std::tuple Fruit::getFruitStats(void)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'int Fruit::getFruitStats(void)' line 12 **in Fruit.cpp**
9. C2371 'Fruit::getFruitStats': redefinition; different basic types line 12 **in Fruit.cpp**
10. argument list for class template "std::tuple" is missing line 13 **in Fruit.h**
11. expected a ')' line 13 **in Fruit.h**
12. expected an identifier line 13 **in Fruit.h**
13. C2955 'std::tuple': use of class template requires template argument list in line 13 **in Fruit.h**
14. C2143 syntax error: missing ')' before ',' 13 **in Fruit.h**
15. C2079 'Fruit::string' uses undefined class 'std::tuple' line 13 **in Fruit.h**
16. C2062 type 'int' unexpected 13; **in Fruit.h**
17. C4430 missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int line 13 **in Fruit.h**

Comment: You declared the function to return an `int`, but are implementing it to return `tuple<string,int>`. Make the declaration match the definition.

Comment: `tuple<string,int>` is not the same as `int`. What was the error when you "_tried changing the Fruit.h's getFruitStats type to integer_"?

Comment: Stop passing std::string by value!!!

Comment: I replaced `int` to `tuple<string,int>` however it prints out more error messages.

Comment: 1. Error C2955 'std::tuple': use of class template requires template argument list
2. Error C2143 syntax error: missing ')' before ','
3. Error C2079 'Fruit::string' uses undefined class 'std::tuple'
4. Error C2062 type 'int' unexpected
5. Error C4430 missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
6. Error C2597 illegal reference to non-static member 'Fruit::string'
There are several more but all of these are error printed in Fruit.h

Comment: On which lines did which errors occur?  You did not give any context.

Comment: They occurred in lines 7, 8, 12, 13 and 21

Comment: Put `#include <tuple>` before `#include "fruit.h"`

Comment: It didn't work. It's still showing the errors.

Comment: The errors don't correspond to this code, there is nothing wrong with the `Fruit::Fruit` line; and "`Fruit::string`" doesnt make any sense.  Please make sure the code shown in the question is *exactly* the code you compiled to get this list of errors. Use copy and paste.

Answer (score 4):

The first error message is the root cause.

The problem is that the declaration and the definition do not match.  In your `.h` file, you declared `Fruit::getFruitStats()` to return `int`.  However, in your `.cpp` file, you defined `Fruit::getFruitStats()` to return `tuple<string,int>`.

To solve this problem, change the return type of the declaration to match the definition.  (...or vice-versa, as long as they match)

I.e. Change `int getFruitStats();` in your `.h` file to `tuple<string,int> getFruitStats();`

Comment: Also note that both the declaration and the definition should match the type that it actually returns.  If you specify the return type as `int`, but still try to return a `tuple<string, int>`, it still won't work even if the return type is the same in both the declaration and definition.

Comment: Tried it but it didn't worked. A lot of errors printed out. You can check my comment above :)

Comment: @MichaelOng Please post the errors here and not there.

Comment: @MichaelOng Do both files have the line `using namespace std;`?  If not, then you will need to write the fully qualified name of every instance of `tuple` and `string`, i.e. `std::tuple` and `std::string`. Do both files `#include <tuple>` and `#include <string>`?

Comment: Both files have '#include <tuple>`, `#include <string>` and `using namespace std;`

Comment: Here's the list of errors 
1 no instance of overloaded function "Fruit::Fruit" matches the specified type line 7;   
2 member "Fruit::string" is not a type name line 7;  
3 C2597 illegal reference to non-static member 'Fruit::string' line 7;   
4 C2146 syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'name' line 7;   
5 C2143 syntax error: missing ';' before '{' line 8;   
6 C2447 '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) line 8;   
7 class "Fruit" has no member "getFruitStats" line 12;

Comment: 8. C2556 'std::tuple<std::string,int> Fruit::getFruitStats(void)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'int Fruit::getFruitStats(void)' line 12;
9. C2371 'Fruit::getFruitStats': redefinition; different basic types line 12
10 argument list for class template "std::tuple" is missing line 13
11 expected a ')' line 13
12 expected an identifier 13
13 C2955 'std::tuple': use of class template requires template argument list 13;
14 C2143 syntax error: missing ')' before ',' 13;
15 C2079 'Fruit::string' uses undefined class 'std::tuple' 13;
16 C2062 type 'int' unexpected 13;

Comment: You should edit your question to post your *complete code*. If you keep posting incomplete fragments we will have no idea what you did wrong because you omit the part you made mistakes. From the errors in the comment you have incorrectly overloaded getFruitStats function, among other things.

Comment: Good idea. I was actually going to edit my original question.